# Extend Line with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have making an AJAX wizard using JQuery and I'm trying to get the top navigation indicators to work properly. So far I have this:

[image]

I'm trying to extend the line when the user pushes "Next Step".

What I would really like is to have it animate to the next step. My initial approach is to have the light gray line just a "border" property of the "ol" property, and then have a normal "img" tag right after the ol and set these CSS properties on the image (which is an image of a small orange line):

```
{
position:absolute;
margin-top:-37px;
margin-left:-3px;
height:13px;
width:400px;
}
```

So I have a "Proceed" function which fades out the current step and fades in the next step. This is all working great. I was thinking I could increase the width of this orange line (using "animate" but the problem is it goes over the Step indicater (the little "o") like this:

[image]

Is there a better way of doing something like this?

I know it's nit picky little issue, but any advice would really help!

Thank you

UPDATE: By the way, I forgot to add that I have many of these wizards with any different number of steps, so if I did it the way I'm trying to do it, I would need to find the length of width between each step, which would be a lot of work. But if it's the only way, then I can do this

Comment: can you put what you have so far in to a demo on http://jsfiddle.net so we can manipulate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this fiddle where next extends the orange bar: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/AS63L/

What you need to do is than on each next you remove the appropriate bubble.

---

Here is an updated fiddle that does it step by step: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/AS63L/5/

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your markup I would create the line and then absolutely position the circles so the line is under them, then you can extend the line and use the left position of the points to dynamically set the width.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would create an image of each entire step (including the lines and circles) and then use a plugin like http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/wipe.html (see the l2r transition) to simulate the line animation between steps. This avoids positioning and the issues you're running in to.

Comment: I see, so have an image for each progress point, thats a good idea. The only thing I couldn't do would be to animate the width of the orange line

Comment: That's true. I read your question too quickly and missed that detail. Sorry about that!

Comment: You could use this "wipe" effect plugin for jquery to simulate the line animating: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/wipe.html (see the l2r transition)

Answer (score 1):

I did it with some inline elements: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZXWQ/3/)

**EDIT**

It was been updated. Take a look here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZXWQ/5/)

Comment: now its basically the same as mine lol, just with different css

Comment: Yes ... You rocked it first ... But I got a more extensible one. Because I don't have to set the max_width ...

Comment: No ... I mean the `#line` css `width` property

Comment: yes I know what you are talking abt -- look at the code, i do not use the variable.

Comment: OK ... man so ... Try to remove the 2nd line of your css code.

Comment: To see that your code is dependant of `width` property and mine's not!

Comment: yours is as well. remove the width from `.progress` on yours and you have an even worse issue. thats what css is there for...

Comment: `.progress` is the class for the inner `span` .. Your `width` is for the top container `div`

Answer (score 0):

```
.meter {background:#eee;height:4px;width:200px;position:relative;margin-top:4px}
.ball,
.bar {position:absolute;background:#f00;}
.ball {border-radius:10px;width:10px;height:10px;margin-top:-3px;left:40px;transition: left .4s}
.bar {height:4px;left:0;width:40px;transition: width .4s}

<div class="meter">
    <div class="ball"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Adjust .bar width and .ball left together via javascript.

Also you could use HTML5 , but that's a pain to style.